# Are the new size classes in Uikit 3 broken?

Tags: css, frontend, getuikit

I'm new to front end development, and I found working with Uikit to be really easy to use. The new Uikit 3 was released yesterday and I'm having worlds of problems. Specifically, in order to use
       .uk-width-1-2
I now have to use
        .uk-width-1-2\@s
I thought @'s were not allowed in CSS? Is that a media query? Where is it pulling from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because certain characters are allowed if escaped by a backslash (`\`). The `@` symbol is one of those characters, so the class `.uk-width-1-2\@s` is valid. More at https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes